# Zoom in and out an image on mouse click using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Here in this application, I've used buttons to zoom in and out an image using MVVM in WPF. On clicking zoom in button, the height and width are increased by a particular amount and vice versa for the zoom out. but I want to achieve the same using a mouse double click. Is there any way to achieve the same using MVVM?

```cs
private ICommand zoomOutCommand;
public ICommand ZoomOutCommand {
    get {
        if (zoomOutCommand == null) {
            zoomOutCommand = new RelayCommand < object > (ZoomOutExecute, OutReturnBool, false);
        }
        return zoomOutCommand;
    }
}
private ICommand zoomInCommand;
public ICommand ZoomInCommand {
    get {
        if (zoomInCommand == null) {
            zoomInCommand = new RelayCommand < object > (ZoomInExecute, InReturnBool, false);
        }
        return zoomInCommand;
    }
}

private void ZoomInExecute(object obj) {
    //  Scale += stepScale;
    Height *= 1.2;
    Width *= 1.2;
}

private bool InReturnBool(object obj) {
    if (Height > 6 * iniWidth) return false;
    else return true;
}

private bool OutReturnBool(object obj) {
    if (Height < 0.1 * iniHeight) return false;
    else return true;
}
private void ZoomOutExecute(object obj) {
    Height *= 0.8;
    Width *= 0.8;
}

private const double iniWidth = 500;
private double width = iniWidth;
public double Width {
    get {
        return width;
    }
    set {
        width = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Width");
    }
}

private const double iniHeight = 500;
private double height = iniHeight;
public double Height {
    get {
        return height;
    }
    set {
        height = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Height");
    }
}
```

Comment: This logic should be inside a control or attached behavior. Then use a `ScaleTransform`. Note that scaling and zooming are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

For a double click you can bind the command this way

```
<Button>
    <Button.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding YourCommand}" />
    </Button.InputBindings>
</Button>
```